# Difference between two Enthalphy equations

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I am revising thermodynamics and in the textbook, the enthalpy equations are stated in two forms.
"H=U+pV" and "h=u+pv". What is the difference between the two equations.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the second for the *specific enthalpy,* meaning the enthalpy per unit mass.  The the first, $H$, is the enthalpy of whatever system (of some arbitrary mass) that we are following. I do not know if this is standard practice though. When I use my definition I always say "where $h$ is the specific enthalpy" so as to make clear what I mean. Do your text books not do this? The units should make it clear. In SI my $H$ has units of Joules, and my $h$ units of Joules per kilogram.

Comment: Another possibility is that the lowercase variables indicate the molar quantities (i.e., the enthalpy, energy, and volume per mole). As you note, this should be defined somewhere in the book.